# Problema al leer una variable en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo problemas al leer una variable cuando paso por primera vez lee bien [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero después al volver a leer no me deja ingresar el nombre [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public void ingresarMusicos(){

```
    int opc;
    Musico datosDelMusico = new Musico ();
    System.out.println("---INGRESANDO MUSICOS---");
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el genero musical del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setGeneroMusical(entrada.nextLine());
     
    System.out.println("Ingrese si aun esta realizando giras(true/false): ");
    datosDelMusico.setActivo(entrada.nextBoolean());
    
     System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setEdad(entrada.nextInt());
    
    cantMusicos.almacenarMusico(datosDelMusico);
    System.out.println("Datos ingresados correctamente...");
    System.out.println("Desea seguir ingresando?(1/2): ");
    System.out.println("1.- SI \n2.- NO");
    
    opc = entrada.nextInt();
    
    if(opc == 1){
        this.ingresarMusicos();
    }
    
}
```

AYUDA PLEASE!

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto?

Comment: publice el metodo como respuesta

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu [primera medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @RuDaHee Ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: @Bicho Ya agregue el código como texto

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que tuve un problema similar y se debe al `entrada.nextLine();`, te sugiero cambiarlo por `entrada.next();` y recuerda declarar el objeto Scanner al inicio de la entidad (Clase)
Quedo pendiente de tu respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Cambie el entrada.nextLine(); a entrada.next(); pero al ingresar el nombre con espacios no me deja ingresar el genero musical por ejemplo si ingreso victor por si solo despues lee el genero pero si ingreso Victor Heredia se salta el ingreso del genero musical y lee altiro la siguiente variable que pido

Comment: Entonces haz lo siguiente, lee el nombre del músico con entrada.nextLine(); y justo debajo en una línea nueva vuelves a poner entrada.nextLine(); para que no se te coma la línea y haga un "Skip"

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya se soluciono.

Answer (score 0):

este es un problema al cargar números en java. Cuando ingresas un número, realmente ingresas dos cosas, un número, y un salto de linea. Este salto de linea se "come" la siguiente petición, ya que queda un poco en el limbo. La solución más fácil pasa por poner un nextLine() despues del nextInt():

```
public void ingresarMusicos(){

    int opc;
    Musico datosDelMusico = new Musico ();
    System.out.println("---INGRESANDO MUSICOS---");
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setNombre(entrada.nextLine());
    
    System.out.println("Ingrese el genero musical del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setGeneroMusical(entrada.nextLine());
     
    System.out.println("Ingrese si aun esta realizando giras(true/false): ");
    datosDelMusico.setActivo(entrada.nextBoolean());
    
     System.out.println("Ingrese la edad del musico: ");
    datosDelMusico.setEdad(entrada.nextInt());
    
    cantMusicos.almacenarMusico(datosDelMusico);
    System.out.println("Datos ingresados correctamente...");
    System.out.println("Desea seguir ingresando?(1/2): ");
    System.out.println("1.- SI \n2.- NO");
    
    opc = entrada.nextInt();
    entrada.nextLine();
    if(opc == 1){
        this.ingresarMusicos();
    }
    
}
```

Otra solución pasaría por capturar los enteros como String y trabajar con ellos como cadenas en lugar de como enteros.

Comment: No entendi mucho la primera solucion jaja, osea tengo que leer primero los numeros enteros y al ultimo los string?

Comment: Buenas, la lectura extra que añades es solo para que capture el salto de linea (cuando apretas enter). Con tu codigo original, cuando haces opc = entrada.nextInt();, si apretas 1, enter, ese salto de linea es capturado por esta otra linea: datosDelMusico.setNombre(entrada.nextLine()); y por eso te "salta" a la siguiente. 
Haciendo una captura del salto de linea sin almacenarlo en nignuna variable solucionas el problema: entrada.nextLine();